# Python WebKitWebView: how to get (generated) source code

Tags: python, webkit, web-scraping

Is it possible to get the generated source code (so including JavaScript added DOM nodes) with Python and WebKit, and if so, how?

```
import webkit
web_view = webkit.WebView()
web_view.open('http://google.com')
```

But then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it here: http://blog.motane.lu/2009/06/18/pywebkitgtk-execute-javascript-from-python/

Comment: could you please elaborate more . The link is broken now

Answer (score 1):

Bind a function to the `loadFinished(bool)` signal, in that function you can use `mainFrame().toHtml()` to get the source code.